# using loadleveler to manage client server application

Tags: client-server, sharing, hosts

I have two applications one in C language [which acts as a TCP server] and other in C++ [which acts as a TCP client]. I have to run them in a cluster which uses loadleveler. The client needs to know the host where the server is running.

Is it possible to make loadleveler use the same host for both client and server application so that I can specify localhost as the server's hostname in the client?

I tried writing in the server's hostname in a file and the client polling the file till it finds a hostname in it, but this requires the loadleveler to process my server and client jobs simultaneously. Also it wastes a lot of processor time.

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks!

pras

Comment: I am now using a static clock-host, where the server puts its hostname and the client keeps checking the clock-host for its server's host. Is it possible to get rid of this handshake?